# Git revert delets every single file in my repo

Tags: git

So I had this issue the past 5 days, every time i try to revert a commit, git goes ahead and deletes every file in the repo.

```
ben@ben-build:~/android/arrow/kernel/motorola/msm8952$ ls -a
.                 COPYING        README          drivers   lib       tools
..                CREDITS        REPORTING-BUGS  firmware  mm        usr
.git              Documentation  android         fs        net       virt
.gitignore        Kbuild         arch            include   samples
.mailmap          Kconfig        block           init      scripts
Android.mk        MAINTAINERS    crypto          ipc       security
AndroidKernel.mk  Makefile       defconfig.mk    kernel    sound
ben@ben-build:~/android/arrow/kernel/motorola/msm8952$ git revert 93bcc70c7a4162cbd1aceb4f1e637fee2e195717
error: could not revert 93bcc70c7... msm8952: Undervolt
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
ben@ben-build:~/android/arrow/kernel/motorola/msm8952$ ls -a
.  ..  .git  drivers
ben@ben-build:~/android/arrow/kernel/motorola/msm8952$
```

Comment: That's kind of shocking, but would make sense if and only if that particular commit had *added* everything that Git just removed. The title of the commit you're reverting (`msm8952: Undervolt`) suggests not, though. If you `git show` that commit, or `git show --name-status` to get just a list of files and corresponding changes, what does that produce?

Comment: using repo sync to download the repository seems to mess up something, i had to manually clone with git clone to fix the issue